# function outside vue, passing data into vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a function that runs outside of a vue component. I want the data it returns passed to the data in the vue component.

```
    <script>
      function example(){
        var item = 'item';
      };

      example();

      export default {
        data(){
          return (this is where I want item represented)
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assign the function to a `const` and call it within one of the  component lifecycle hooks:

```
const example = function (){
    return 'item';
};

export default {
    created () {
        this.item = example()
    },
    data(){
      return {
         item: null
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 11):

See Working Demo :

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    item: "Hi"
  }
});


function example(){
      app.item='Hello How R You ?';
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<button onclick="example()" >Click ME</button>
  {{ item }}
</div>
```

Comment: Why this isn't the accepted answer? It's the simplest and easiest method.